# Column requires refresh upon saving

Tags: workflow, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Good morning,

I have a column with the following calculation:

="PX-"&CONCATENATE(REPT("0",3-LEN(ID-6)),ID-6)

I had to use 6 to offset the ID number to provide a PX number.  The problem is that when a user makes a change to an existing form or adds a new item, the PX Number field reflects "PX - 0 - 6".  I then need to go into List Settings, go into the column "PX Number" and hit "OK".  This action updates the column and reflects the correct value.

How do I create a Workflow or what would I need to update so that this field auto-refreshes to update the PX number correctly?

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You cannot use the [ID] in a calculated field in a list since the ID does not exist until after a record is created and the calculation has already been done at this stage.

The only way is via a Workflow. First remove the calculated field from the list and replace it with a text field. In SharePoint Designer (I'm using SPD 2013) click on Workflow and List Workflow then select your List from the drop down menu.
[image]

Give the workflow a name and then ensure you select the Start Workflow Automatically when an item is created.
[image]

Then click on Edit Workflow and add the following actions

```
Set item to PX-
If Current Item:ID is less than 10
    Set Variable: item to [%Variable: item%]000[%Current Item:ID%]
Else if Current Item:ID is less than 100
    Set Variable: item to [%Variable: item%]00[%Current Item:ID%]
Else if Current Item:ID is less than 1000
    Set Variable: item to [%Variable: item%]0[%Current Item:ID%]
Else
    Set Variable: item to [%Variable: item%][%Current Item:ID%]
Set PX Number to Variable:item
```

You will need to increase the number of Else if statements to provide the correct number of padded zeros. *item* is a Workflow variable.

Hope this helps